# Decent magento soap v2 documentation

Tags: magento, soap

I'm looking for a site where the magento soap v2 documentation is present.

Now the original magento site is **seriously** lacking in even the most basic documentation.

What I want is very simple: An overview of ALL possible soap methods and what kind of parameters I need to pass to them to get something usefull or store something usefull in the store.

I've been googling for two weeks, trying everything I can think of and the only thing I find are other frustrated programmers complaining about the same thing.

Does anyone know any resource that gives at least an overview of possible soap methods and parameters that can be passed to them?

The person giving a good answer will recieve 200 points in two days(if anyone gives a good answer anyways)

Comment: best Magento's documentation is in app/code/core/

Comment: right... and how do I find the v2 documentation in there???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be good start:

- http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/
- http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/
- http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2-soap-unit-testing/

For this part on where to find all possible SOAP methods with parameters implemented in Magento SOAP API, the answer couldn't be simpler:

Please do not search on Google, but rather open your Magento SOAP wsdl file with your browser or save it on disk.Then open it with some tool that can make more beautiful view on wsdl files and you will find all the methods along with needed parameters.
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/ here you can find a little part about wsdl. It should be enough for you to be able to start using SOAP API.
Your WSDL url should look like this:

- http://yourmagentodomain.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1

Comment: The inchoo site is the closest thing to having a documentation and the wdsl I have already printed out(91 pages) and am studying those already....
But it would have helped if the magento development team would have taken the time to write a simple manual with : These soap functions area there, they return this and expect this and this is the way to set up the filters...
Now I have read a bloody xml file, have marked multple colors for readability and try to figure out how to use it...

Hence my question for a simple site...